# How to make Angular router links disable scrolling to the top of the page?

Tags: angular, routes, router

How can i disable scrolling to the top when clicking Angular router links? 
I have three sub routes which i wish navigate between on same parent page and I don't want the app to scroll on top of the page when users click those links.
So I want the page to stay in exact same point it was before clicking the link.
Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the module where you import `RoutingModule.forRoot()`

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' })],
```

This will disable scroll reset for routing in the whole app. If you need more control you can implement a custom logic following a template like this:

```
class AppModule {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
   router.events.pipe(
     filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)
   ).subscribe(e => {
     if (e.position) {
       // backward navigation
       viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
     } else if (e.anchor) {
       // anchor navigation
       viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
     } else {
       // forward navigation
       viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
     }
   });
  }
}
```